# Updating database from bootstrap modal form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

With reference to my previous question > [Displaying php echo $row data into bootstrap modal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760194/displaying-php-echo-row-data-into-bootstrap-modal-form)

I have set the "SAVE" button data-id when I clicked on the row edit button with `$(".saveContact").attr('data-id', result[0]['id']);`

In the jQuery for #editForm submit, I've retrieved the id by `var uid = $(".saveContact").attr('data-id');` and pass it to **updateContact.php**, however nothing happens when I click on the save button and the modal just stays open. May I know if I did not pass the id correctly or my UPDATE statement is incorrect in updating the database?

**tables.php modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="editForm" role="form">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Contact</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group animated fadeIn">
                    <label for="nameInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="nameInput" placeholder="Name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group animated fadeIn">
                    <label for="companyInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="company" name="company" class="form-control" id="companyInput" placeholder="Company" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group animated fadeIn">
                    <label for="posInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Position</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="position" name="position" class="form-control" id="posInput" placeholder="Position/Job Title">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group animated fadeIn">
                    <label for="contactInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact Number</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="number" name="contact" class="form-control" id="contactInput" placeholder="Office/Mobile Number" data-error="Please enter a valid mobile number" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group animated fadeIn">
                    <label for="emailInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group animated fadeIn">
                    <label for="genderInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="gender" name="gender" class="form-control" id="genderInput" placeholder="Male/Female">
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="idInput" placeholder="ID">
                </div>
                </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button id="editContact" type="submit" class="saveContact btn btn-primary" data-id="">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

**jQuery to submit form**

```
$("#editForm").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var uid = $("#idInput").val();
var name = $("#nameInput").val();
var company = $("#companyInput").val();
var position = $("#posInput").val();
var contact = $("#contactInput").val();
var email = $("#emailInput").val();
var gender = $("#genderInput").val();

var dataForm = 'name=' + name + '&company=' + company + '&position=' + position + '&contact=' + contact + '&email=' + email + '&gender=' + gender + '&id=' + uid;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../admin/dataprocess/updateContact.php',
    data: dataForm,
    success: function(html){
        if(html == "success"){
            $('#contactsTable').dataTable().reload();
            $('#editModal').modal('toggle');
        }
    }
    });

});
```

**updateContact.php**

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE businesscontact SET name = ?, company = ?, position = ?, phone = ?, email = ?, gender = ? WHERE id = $id");
$stmt-> bind_param("ssssss", $name, $company, $position, $contact, $email, $gender);
if($stmt->execute()){
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo(mysqli_error($link);
}


mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: you're escaping and using a prepared statement, why? that could have adverse effects

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, I'm still new to php. So I would just need to set `$name = $_POST['name']` and having prepared statements is sufficient?

Comment: just use the prepared statement; get rid of `mysqli_real_escape_string()` altogether

Comment: someone popped an answer below; I honestly don't see why they wrote: *"Your submit button is outside the form"*.

Comment: so, what's the status of the question? I'm trying to lend a helping hand, yet you've not told us what's not working and given the answer below. You'll need to either ping me or place a comment under the answer given.

Comment: you realize that this `echo(mysqli_error($link);` is a syntax error and php's error reporting would have signaled that part. Your methods also coincide with post/get

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for pointing that out, it was indeed just that that caused the update to not work.

Comment: you're welcome Kayden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I stated in comments;

```
echo(mysqli_error($link); // <- theoretically missing a )
```

is causing the error here, since there was a missing bracket.

> *@Fred-ii- Thanks for pointing that out, it was indeed just that that caused the update to not work. – Kayden"*

You don't even need the "echo" here anyway.

Just use the following, which is all you need. It will trigger an "echo"'d error on its own:

```
mysqli_error($link);
```

Since "echo" is a language construct, brackets are not required.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Error reporting would have helped you here.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php